# SolrCluster formation like elasticsearch

Tags: solr

How to form solr cluster like as elasticsearch.I already saw document clustering.I need solr cluster with one master and multiple slave with out replication.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to ask you question: Why do you want multiple slave core?

If you want to go for Load Balancing or High Availability i.e. for Failure Mechanism then replication is the solution in SOLR along with SOLRCLOUD.

So if you want slave for both the above thing then why dont you go for replication mode.

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean by 'like as ElasticSearch' => 'distributed' , so use SolrCloud
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/SolrCloud